# Path planning algorithm to run my floor cleaning robot/zig zag path travel

Tags: arduino

I am creating a floor cleaning robot with obstacle detection as my final year project. The basic task of the robot is to clean the floor while avoiding obstacles using an ultrasonic sensor. The travelling path needs to be in an S shape to cover entire area of the floor.

What easy algorithms are suitable for vacuum cleaning and turning automatically with the help of ultrasonic obstacle avoidance?

Comment: How do you plan on recognizing obstacles? Will you have multiple depth sensors?

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* ishan, but I'm afraid that questions which ask for recommendations are effectively opinion polls, which are [discouraged on stack exchange](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/01/17/real-questions-have-answers/). We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*, so questions which ask for recommendations off-topic. Please take a look at [ask] & [about] for more information on how stack exchange works.

Comment: I have edited your question to better fit our community guidelines @ihsan.